# javascript curry/partial function invokation for object functions

Tags: javascript

I want a 'curry' like function - this kind of thing

```
function invoker (fn) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
    return function () {
       return fn.apply(null, args);
    };
}
```

But I want the user to be able to do

```
invoker(f)
```

or

```
invoker(foo.bar)
```

I cant find the correct magic incantation to do this. All the examples I see require the scope object to be passed in separately; which is error prone and not natural. IE

```
invokerx(foo.bar, foo)
```

IS there anyway to do this? I dont mind having 2 different functions

```
invokeG(f)
invokeO(foo.bar)
```

EDIT : clarification

```
'f' is a global scope function
'foo' is an object
'bar is a method on that object
```

IE I want this curry tool to work with'free' functions as well as with object functions.

Having to go

```
<curry function>(foo.bar,foo)
```

seems kinda clunky, I have have to say 'foo' twice

Comment: Saying *"I want the user to be able to do `invoker(f)` or `invoker(foo.bar)`"* doesn't describe what you want. Please describe in words the problem you're trying to solve. EDIT: Maybe you want the user to be able to bind a context to the function?

Comment: What are `f` and `foo.bar` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `apply` is the `this` that is available to the function.  Since you're passing `null`, `this` will get mapped to `window`.

The following modification will work:

```
function invoker (fn, target) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.apply(arguments, [2]);

    if(typeof fn === 'string')
        fn = (target || window)[fn];

    return function () {
       return fn.apply(target || null, args);
    };
}

// Either will work:
invoker(foo.bar, foo);
invoker('bar', foo);

// Any of these will work:
invoker(escape, null);
invoker(escape, window);
invoker('escape', null);
invoker('escape', window);
```

**UPDATE** Added a slight change to add support for name passing so you don't have to pass the object name twice.

**UPDATE 2** Since we're currying, we need there to always be two arguments.

Comment: right, but this requires the caller to use 2 different call signatures. My feeling is that invoker(foo.bar, foo) is redundant , I already said foo once

Comment: You know that, and I know that, but JavaScript doesn't know that.  I'll add an alternate solution that doesn't require multiple instances of 'foo', but it will be less efficient.

Comment: cmon brian, one more heroic effort and I am sure you can find a really nice solution. You are getting pretty close with the 'invoker('bar', foo), but we are still not quite there :-)

Comment: @pm100: Short of doing something horrible, like `invoker('foo.bar')`, that's as close as you can get

Comment: @Eric how would I do that , why is it horrific?

Comment: First off, it would only work if foo was a global variable.  Second, it would require use of `eval` (scary/slow) or string parsing (slow).  In practice, there are many examples of curry functions bound to objects and they all need a second parameter which often results in typing the object name twice.  It's just how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. When you do `invoker(foo.bar)`, `invoker` has no way of knowing that the argument is a member function of `foo`. Functions do not store their "owner", and `invoker` is just passed a reference to a function.

The closest you can get is to use [`function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like this:

```
invoker(foo.bar.bind(foo))
```

Comment: I guess thats it, i wanted to find the 'owner' of the function. I am surprised that apply doesnt have some variant that allows this.

Comment: Actually, the `.bind` function _is_ a currying function so you don't really need `invoker` here.  `var boundBar = foo.bar.bind(foo)` is all you need.  Otherwise you're currying a curried function.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Currying